# script to detect outdate cms in linux?

Tags: linux, wordpress, joomla, cms

Is there any script (free or paid) use to detect outdated version of joomla & wordpress and inform the customers by email (cpanel) to upgrade immediately ?

Comment: That's rather easy to write yourself...

Answer (score 2):

There aren't any scripts that I'm aware of for Cpanel, but there are numerous plugins for joomla and wordpress to do this kind of stuff.

You can include them in the default installs.